# Css file not loading when the HTML page loads on Safari when the CSS file is kept in a different folder

Tags: html, css, safari

Css file not loading when the HTML page loads on Safari when the CSS file is kept in a different folder.

Folder Structure :

->UI Learning {css, images, templates}

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="hello.css">


</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>My Page</h1>
        <p>This is some text.</p> 

        <div class="row">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This works fine.

However when I put the CSS in a different folder (css folder) then the css file does not load.

href="../css/hello.css"

This does not work.

However Chrome and Firefox have no problem loading. In Safari, I get this error.

Failed to load resource: The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 1.)

Answer (score 1):

Best practice would to be to add a / in front of the .. href="/../css/hello.css. if the ui folder is in the root folder you need to /ui/css

Answer (score 0):

Try `href="/css/hello.css"`. This states that the `css` folder is at root level.